# Debugging Solution Errors

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

I have the below issue importing a solution

> Cannot import component EntityRelationship:
>   b3a31c43-b484-e511-80f9-3863bb3640b8. The publisher of the solution
>   that is being imported does not match the publisher of the solution
>   that installed this component.

Anyone help with the best way to debug this using CRM Online, using on premise I would of queried the database to find the actual object causing the problem?

Comment: Pretty sure the SDK has an example of how to query Entity Relationships...

Comment: Are you trying to import a managed solution into a system where you have (partly) the same unmanaged customizations in place?

Comment: I suspect Henk is right about unmanaged and managed customizations colliding.  If not - Open the solution and find the EntityRelationships section: that ID should give you more information on which relationship is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Yes its when importing a managed solution into a solution which has partly the same unmanaged customisations. I know what the error is telling me but I cannot find the component it has the issue with. Must be a tool where you can easily identify a component via its guid like querying the database with on premise.

Comment: theres 2 very straight forward options that I generally use to find the problem component (there's more, but imho these are the easiest).  1) look through the log file for the component - usually there is enough info to find it and identify which component (EntityRelationship in this case) is causing the problem.  Alternatively 2) open any EntityRelationship (1:N, N:1, or N:N) and find and replace the ID of the record on the page within the url with the id of the record in the error message.  This will navigate you to the problem relationship, and then you can do something about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joseph just to add to this post. I had a similar idea as the one you described in point 2 however, this will not work because even if you replace the relationship id with your component id the url also contains an entity guid therefore you would have to do this for each entity in your Crm instance until you find the record.